# Process.Start in Azure Website

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, wkhtmltopdf, azure-web-app-service

I have an ASP.NET MVC 5 app where I need to invoke wkhtml2pdf.exe in my Azure website using `Process.Start`. Locally everthing works fine. But it seems my app stuck at `Process.Start` line. Is starting a process is supported on Azure?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

ramiramilu's answer is actually not correct. You can run any exe you want ([check this for example](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console)). The problem you are hitting is not in running an exe, it's something specific to `wkhtml2pdf.exe` itself. That exe uses a bunch of `GDI+` calls on Windows for rendering the PDF and that is what's not allowed in Azure Websites sandbox (the `GDI+` calls, not running an exe).

Using a WebJob won't help either because WebJobs run in the same context as the site which means under the same sandbox.

**Edit:**

There is nothing special to how you would launch an external process on Azure Websites than how you would do it normally with C#. Again the problem you are facing is with `wkhtml2pdf.exe` and not with the general concept of launching a process.

Here is a sample that you can try that launches `cmd.exe` and reads what is written on stdout

```
var processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = "/c echo \"test\"",
    FileName = @"c:\windows\system32\cmd.exe",
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    UseShellExecute = false
};

var process = Process.Start(processStartInfo);

using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(process.StandardOutput.BaseStream))
{
    ViewBag.MessageFromExe = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
}
```

`ViewBag.MessageFromExe` will have the value `"test"` you can verify that on your view and you can run that just fine in Azure Websites

Comment: Do you have any running example on ASP.NET website?

Comment: Well my point is that using ASP.Net MVC5 application, it is not possible to run Process.Start() in AzureWebsite.

Comment: Thanks. Hopefully I can use it in ASP.NET(MVC 5) as well Correct?

Comment: [At beginning 2016 Chrome dropped GDI+ in favor of DirectWrite](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/1acd6b6af8c9ef59fe7227faff4585310e5c2ec8). This caused new wkhtml2pdf.exe to work on Azure Website.

Comment: Thanks for this @ahmelsayed. What processes are or are not allowed in an Azure Website/App sandbox? Is there any way to find the exact cause of why an .exe does not execute? I'm guessing this is the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841339/running-exe-on-azure

Comment: Microsoft published an article that, to my surprise, incorrectly (?) asserts that you cannot start processes in Azure Websites and that you can in WebJobs and the author got `wkhtml2pdf` to work there : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt707529.aspx - but I think it worked for him because of the coincidental change in WebKit that uses DirectWrite.

Comment: Update (12/12/2018) According to the [Azure Sandbox Documentation](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Web-App-sandbox#unsupported-frameworks) WkHtmlToPdf is now supported, with the limitation that GDI+ is still restricted.  Works fine if you only use system installed fonts.

Answer (score 0):

You can use an alternative way to do PDF generation that will work in Azure WebApps. See [this blog](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/07/25/pdf-generation-and-loading-file-based-certificates-in-azure-websites/).