# Run an .exe with asp.net core and Azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-core, ffmpeg

I'm writing an API that encode a video using **ffmpeg.exe** uploaded from users. To do this I just put the FFmpeg into a folder on my server:

```
C:\home\site\wwwroot\ffmpeg
```

This works fine with a single user. But if I try to upload and encode two or more video at the same time, something goes wrong and the backend crash. Probably because two or more processes are trying to use ffmpeg.exe at same time.

My question is: Is this an wrong approach? I'm using Azure as platform, I need to encode videos using ffmpeg. So what's the best practice?

Thanks!

Comment: Please update the codes about how you use FFMPEG inside the asp.net core.

Answer (score 0):

> Run an .exe with asp.net core and Azure

- In `WebRole` and `WorkerRole`, Windows Azure allows you to run  EXEs.
- On Azure, you could run an .exe in a web role

As per the document - [Run background tasks with WebJobs in Azure App Service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-create)

> Deploy WebJobs by using the [Azure portal](https://portal.azure.com/) to upload an executable or script. You can run background tasks in the Azure App Service.

Please refer [Azure WebJobs SDK for event-driven background processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/webjobs-sdk-get-started) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28305168) for more information